# How homonyms in glossary are mentioned in latex

Tags: glossaries

More than once the same name type entry in \newglossaryentry is not permitted. How do we indicate the homonyms in glossaries then

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have two entries with the same name, so I'm not sure what problem you're running into. Obviously, you need to give them different keys. You can also find examples specifically about this in the documentation of `glossaries`.

Comment: Please find the manuals at ctan.org: https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries

Comment: The labels are different but the key or name happens to be same... The problem still persist